# Infinite loop with SplQueue

Tags: php, queue, spl

I need a queue where I add objects while working the queue (first in first out).
In addition, I keep track of not having duplicate objects in a hashmap.

```
<?php

$test = new \SplQueue();
$done = array();

// Put 'test a' in queue
$test->enqueue('test a');

// While we have objects in the queue...
while ($test->valid()) {
    // Echo the current object
    $current = $test->current();
    echo $current, PHP_EOL;

    // Remove the current object and add it to "done"
    $test->dequeue();
    $done[$current] = 1;

    // Add more to queue
    $new = array('test a', 'test b', 'test c');
    foreach ($new as $newObject) {
        if (! isset($done[$newObject])) {
            $test->enqueue($newObject);
        }
    }
}
```

In PHP codepad, I don't get any result with this.
What is wrong?

Update: After a while I get output:

```
test a 
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /code/NIPg42 on line 25
PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /code/NIPg42 on line 25
```

I do dequeue and test for already done objects, why is this an infinite loop?

Line 25 is `$test->enqueue($newObject);`

Comment: You'll have to provide a correct initial node (with `$test->rewind()`, like in [this demo](https://eval.in/274359)). Have to say I'm not really sure why do you want to use SplQueue this way.

Comment: It's more natural to work with Queue without using `current` at all; otherwise you'll have to make sure its current node is indeed current. I'll describe the possible approach in my answer, if you'd like me to.

Comment: What does the `valid` method do exactly? For me, it has different behavior than `isEmpty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, it's easier (and more natural, too) to work with SplQueue, using two basic methods *only*: `enqueue` to put an item at the end of the queue, and `dequeue` to extract the item you'll have to process from the beginning of the queue. This means getting rid of `current`, using the *result* of `dequeue` instead:

```
$current = $test->dequeue();
$done[$current] = 1;
var_dump($current); // or any other processing
```

As an attempt to dequeue an empty list causes an Error, you'll have to check for it first. So your code becomes similar to this:

```
$test = new \SplQueue();
$done = array();

// Put 'test a' in queue
$test->enqueue('test a');

// While we have objects in the queue...
while (!$test->isEmpty()) {
    $item = $test->dequeue();
    $done[$item] = 1;
    var_dump($item); 

    // Add more to queue
    $new = array('test a', 'test b', 'test c');
    foreach ($new as $newObject) {
        if (! isset($done[$newObject])) {
            $test->enqueue($newObject);

// without this line, `test c` will be enqueued twice.
            $done[$newObject] = 1; 
        }
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/274382). As you see, there's another change here: setting a hash before doing `enqueue`. If you indeed want to make a HashQueue (of a sort), I'd suggest making your own class (extending or using SplQueue); the key would be accompanying each `enqueue` operation with the corresponding check/addition to hash.

Comment: So I did use SplQueue the wrong way, your way is indeed more natural, thanks!

Comment: I am already extending SplQueue to keep track of processed objects; very good idea there. Didn't put that up to keep the code in question simple.